# Fingerprint sensor for ubuntu

Tags: drivers, hp, fingerprint-reader, lsusb

I had recently switched to ubuntu from windows.
After switching , my validity fingerprint sensor stop working.
how to use it. I tried many stuffs on internet such as fingerprint gui tools but can't use it.
But, my sensor is already dectected using lsusb command 
`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0007 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS451 Fingerprint Reader`

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the fingerprint sensor you have doesn't appear to be compatible with Linux at all. Often the manufacturer of the finger print sensor device will make Windows drivers available, but not similar drivers for Linux. The community may be able to make a driver, but often that's difficult as technical details about the device are kept secret by the manufacturer. Sadly I don't think you'll get this working any time soon on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for reply.